# IIS 6 "Dead" app pools can't be stopped or recycled

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

On a production machine that I manage, the app pools periodically die. After they die, it seems impossible to stop or reset them without issuing an iisreset. In this case, I use the word "die" to mean that the sites hosted by the app pool no longer respond to requests.

There are 7 app pools; 4 never die, and the other 3 die irregularly. In the past, a pool has gone down just an hour after an iisreset. I am nearly certain that the problem in each pool is being caused by some app in the pool. Eventually I'll track down that problem.

Here's why I need your help. Once a pool dies, I can't seem to stop or recycle it. In the IIS Manager, trying to recycle a dead pool freezes the manager and I am forced to force kill it. Trying to stop a dead pool causes a hang which eventually ends with an error message that the pool did not respond to the stop or control request. The only way I have been able to bring the app pool(s) back up has been to do an iisreset.

After a pool dies, it does not appear in the iisapp.vbs output.

There are no signs of trouble in the Application Event Log.

The system is Windows Server 2003 R2 SP 2. The app pools which are having problems are populated by ASP.NET web applications.

What's going on here? Is there some command line way to cause an app pool to (re)start? Is there something wrong with my configuration that is keeping me from recycling one of these dead app pools?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like those "dead" pools are more or less stuck somewhere, maybe in an infinite loop, so they're not answering stop/recycle requests from IIS.

What happens if you have a look at the Task Manager for "w3wp.exe" processes? You should have some of them, each one serving one application pool; if this is an infinite loop problem, the process servicing the "dead" pool will be heavily using CPU time (tipically maxing out a single CPU core); you can identify it from this and kill it from the Task Manager.

Comment: If you use Process Explorer from Sysinternals, you can find the w3wp.exe process that has your application pool name in the command line somewhere so that you know you're killing the right one.

Comment: @mfinni: nice, didn't know that.

Comment: Process Explorer (actually, all of the SysInternals tools) always go into c:\bin on any machine I work on, and that gets put into the %PATH% . Along with forfiles.exe , baretail.exe , robocopy.exe , and windirstat.exe

Comment: I've looked in the task manager when a pool has died and haven't noticed any extraordinary w3wp.exe stats on any of the running instances. I'll be sure to check with Process Explorer next time to get an idea of the stats on the bad pool (and be sure I'm looking at the right one).

Comment: between procexp and procmon, you might even be able to get an idea of what the problem is. Not as well as stepping through the code or putting better logging/debugging into it, but it's something. Also - if you can, put each application into its own application pool. Slightly more overhead, but this way you only kill the troublesome one when you have to do that.

Comment: I had a dead app pool this morning, so I had a chance to examine things with procexp. Strangely, there was no w3wp process for the app pool which was dead. All of the other running app pools did have an instance as expected.

Comment: @Eric: this means the process had crashed and exited, and this is the reason the app pool was dead. Now, as to *why* it crashed, well, that's a whole different matter...

Comment: Indeed, the question of _why_ is certainly one that I'd like to find the answer to. However, my more immediate question is whether there is a way to resurrect or restart the process that should be hosting the app pool. Can this be done without an IIS reset?

Comment: The IIS manager should show the pool as stopped and allow you to restart it, that's the usual behaviour when a pool crashes. I don't know why your IIS seems to not be able to detect the failure...